# Reinforcement Deep Learning for object detection

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

After reading the state of the Art of object detection using the CNN's(R-CNN,Faster R-CNN,YOLO,YOLOv2,SSD) I was wondering if there is an efficient method that use deep learning with reinforcement learning for object detection ?

Comment: That's a bit vague/open-ended, do you have anything in mind? For instance, do you have any environment or problem where you are hoping RL will apply? RL needs a specific framing of a problem, it isn't an architecture choice such as R-CNN, YOLO etc.

Comment: I meant they use RL for example instead of Region proposal or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my extent of my knowledge, RL is used as a model for attention mechanism in object detection field (particularly the REINFORCE algorithm which is a 'flavor' of policy gradient methods). You can take a look at one of the papers that first proposed the method: [RAM](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5542-recurrent-models-of-visual-attention.pdf)